# Trying to add class using if and else but not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am trying to add class using if and else,but its not working beyond if not reaching to else.

```
$('.headings aside').click(function() {
    if ($(this).children('span').hasClass("fa-caret-up")) {
      $(this).children('span').addClass('borderGap');
      alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    } else {
      alert("Second Alert");
      $(this).children('span').removeClass('borderGap');
    };
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your html markup.

Comment: else {
      alert("Second Alert");
      $(this).children('span').removeClass('borderGap');
    } => use this (removed ;)

Comment: Can you please provide html code.

Comment: It actually works ... but only one at a time: http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/LL9j7fzr/

Comment: put `$(this).children('span')` into a variable, there is no reason to keep looking it up.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works:

```
<aside> 
    <span class="no_class">no class</span>
</aside>

$('aside').click(function() {
    if ($(this).children('span').hasClass("fa-caret-up")) {
      $(this).children('span').addClass('borderGap');
      alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    } else {
      alert("Second Alert");
      $(this).children('span').removeClass('borderGap');
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cpyq6a5r/

The thing is, the behaviour will depend on the html markup.

Example: if you have 2 spans

```
<span class="no_class">no class</span>
<span class="fa-caret-up">no class</span>
```

it will never go into the "else" statement, because aside has a span with class "fa-caret-up"

Answer (score 0):

I you are looking at getting both add and remove applied "on the same click", try ...

```
$('.headings aside').click(function() {
    if ($(this).children('span').hasClass("fa-caret-up")) {
      $(this).children('span').addClass('borderGap');
      alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    }
    if (!$(this).children('span').hasClass("fa-caret-up")) {
      alert("Second Alert");
      $(this).children('span').removeClass('borderGap');
    }
});
```

Which will now check for caret and not caret ... in your original code, if any span had a caret, then the else is not run.  Here, both conditions are checked independently.